# How do I get selected value from a bootstrap select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the selected text, not value, from my bootstrap drop down, but my .text() statement is returning a string that contains all the values with a '\n' in between.

Here is my rendered html

```
<select class="form-control" id="SpaceAccommodation" name="YogaSpaceAccommodation">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">1-4</option>
    <option value="1">5-9</option>
    <option value="2">10-15</option>
    <option value="3">16-20</option>
    <option value="4">20+</option>
</select>
```

Here is my javascript, but selectedText returns '5-9\n10-15\n16-20\n20+'
I want it to return 5-9 or 10-15, etc..

```
$('#SpaceAccommodation').change(function () {

    var selectedText = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Try this $( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();

Answer (score 45):

You can get the selected value's text with `$(this).find("option:selected").text()`.

```js
$('#SpaceAccommodation').change(function () {
    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    
    $(".test").text(selectedText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="SpaceAccommodation" name="YogaSpaceAccommodation">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">1-4</option>
    <option value="1">5-9</option>
    <option value="2">10-15</option>
    <option value="3">16-20</option>
    <option value="4">20+</option>
</select>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: is `option:selected`  a jquery selector or a CSS selector ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/ - it's a jquery extension, not a part of the CSS spec

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you tell me what should I do if I want a comma separated string of all selected options? like '1,2,3,4'

Answer (score 6):

[Fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/3UP3a/95/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.chzn-select').change(function () {
         alert( $('.chzn-select option:selected').text());
     });
 });

<select id="second" class="chzn-select" style="width: 100px">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

This is based on the css3 psuedo-class `:selected`. It's very similar to [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked), I couldn't find docs for `:selected`

Comment: Not a css3 psuedo-class; it's a jquery extension: https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone cares, I've got another solution. I just looked at the arguments from the docs. You can do something like this (Assuming you've set the value tag of the option element.:

```
 $('#type_dropdown')
                .on('changed.bs.select',
                    function(e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
                        alert(e.target.value);
                    });
        });
```

See https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/